# Upper Bounds and Least Upper Bounds

Tags: real-analysis

When defining a least upper bound, how can you have an interval such as (0,1) and have an upper bound of 2?

Comment: Have you seen this in a book or is it a possibility you're wondering about?

Answer (score 1):

$2$ is an upper bound because $\forall x\in (0,1),\, x\leq 2$.

Comment: Why 2 and not 1.5 or 3?

Comment: $1.5$ and $3$ are also upper bounds. Actually, every real number greater or equal than $1$ is an upper bound. And $1$ is the smallest one, because for any $\varepsilon>0$, $1-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound of $(0,1)$.

Comment: And this is because the interval is open?  If it was [0,1], then the UB and LUB would be 1?

Comment: No, if it were $[0,1]$, what I said would still be true.

Answer (score 1):

Given any set $A$ (partially) ordered by a relation $\preceq,$ and any subset $B\subseteq A,$ we say that $x$ is ***an*** *upper bound of* $B$ *in* $A$ if for every $y\in B$ we have $y\preceq x.$ We say that $z\in A$ is ***the*** *least upper bound of* $B$ *in* $A$ if for every upper bound $x$ of $B$ in $A$, we have $z\preceq x.$

In the context $A=\Bbb R,$ $B=(0,1),$ $\preceq=\leq,$ we have that $2$ is an upper bound of $B$ in $A,$ and $1$ is the least upper bound of $B$ in $A$. The same is true if we take $B=[0,1],$ instead, say.

If we were instead to take $A=(0,1)\cup\{2\},$ then $2$ would in fact be the *least* upper bound of $B$ in $A$ (since it's the *only* upper bound of $B$ in $A$).

If we were to instead take $A=(0,1),$ then there *is no* upper bound of $B$ in $A,$ and so no least upper bound of $B$ in $A.$

If we take $A=\Bbb R,$ $B=\emptyset,$ $\preceq=\leq,$ then *every* element of $A$ is (vacuously) an upper bound of $B$ in $A$, but there is no least upper bound of $B$ in $A$.

---

In summary: When considering questions of upper bounds, one needs to keep in mind the two sets in question, and how the (partial) ordering relation is defined. At that point, one needs to check the definition of (least) upper bound to see what elements (if any) fit the definition.

Comment: I will chew on this for awhile and get back with any further questions.  Thanks.

Comment: Of course! I gave you quite a bit to chew on (which will hopefully help to clarify the concepts in your mind), so feel free to ask me for clarification about anything that confuses you.